# Outlook Agent for retrieving mails and showing it

Tags: c#, wpf, email, datagrid, exchangewebservices

Please forgive my noobieness and my English. I am new to WPF and home made Agents. My assignment is to make an Outlook Agent, that will connect with Outlook and retrieves every email from a specific folder. It should also get specific data like Body, Sender, SentOn, subject etc. Also it should pre parse the emailbox for unread emails.

So I think I am retrieving all these details correctly, correct me if I am wrong. The next step I need to take is where I get stuck. Now that I am retrieving the right information how do I put my specific data like Body, sender etc. in my WPF datagrid.

This is my Outlook Connection method:

```
public void ConnectieOutlook() {     

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);

    //service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "{Active Directory ID}", "{Password}", "{Domain Name}" );

    service.AutodiscoverUrl("******@***.nl");

    /*FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
        WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
        new ItemView(10));*/
    SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
    FolderId InboxId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "**********@****.nl");

    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(InboxId, new ItemView(5));

    foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
    {
        ((EmailMessage)item).Load();
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        /// URLGRID.ItemsSource = findResults.Items;
        findResults.Where(t => t is EmailMessage).Select(Item => new
        {
            item.DateTimeReceived,
            ((EmailMessage)item).Sender.Name,
            item.Subject,
            item.InternetMessageHeaders,
            item.Body,
            item.Attachments
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my datagrid loaded method in my MainWindow.xaml.cs. As you will see it is empty because I really don't know where to start. URLGRID is the name of my Datagrid.

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    URLGRID.
}
```

How do I fill this URLGRID with my data? Please don't be harsh, remember that I got thrown in the sea and have been told to make this agent to survive. So I am definitely missing some basic knowledge but I don't know where to search for it. Any suggested tutorials will be very welcome:)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**About Control to use :**
Well, I would recommend you to first use `ListView` as you would be having only readonly data while showing read/unread Email.
Difference between `ListView` and `DataGrid` is just one. Editing. You need editing use `DataGrid`, otherwise use `ListView`. You can edit in `ListView` also but it is easier and build in `DataGrid`. Otherwise, whatever can be displayed in `DataGrid`, can be displayed in `ListView`.

You can read [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx) for a better understanding of `DataGrid` and also about the major differences between `ListView` and `DataGrid`.

**Program flow** You should use ObservableCollection to bind your control so that any new item retrieved from server can be shown seamlessly in the control. So you can bind the ItemsSource of control with `ObservableCollection<Item>>`. For this you don't require `DataGrid_Loaded` event. If your flow fetches the email either on load of window or click of a button then add those items in the bind collection. However, if should keep in mind that if your program fetches records in background thread then you should be using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method to update the collection asynchronously.

**Display :** In case you are using ListView, then write a `ItemTemplate` based on display need. The `ItemTemplate` datatemplate can define the child controls which will show the various properties of email like body, subject, to/from.

Comment: @user3599415 - does the answer addresses your query?